# How to define structure for the generic in TS

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a method that returns generic T. I want it to be impossible to transfer everything you want to the generic, but only Record structure.

```
type CatalogQueries = {type: 'pickup' | 'delivery'}
type CartQueries = {type?: 'pickup' | 'delivery'; item: number}
type CheckoutQueries = string

const parser = new Parser()
// ✅ Good because generic is Record type
parser.parseQuery<CatalogQueries>(catalogSearchParams)
parser.parseQuery<CartQueries>(cartSearchParams)

// ❌ there must be an error because there is no record structure
parser.parseQuery<CheckoutQueries>(cartSearchParams)

class Parser {
  parseQuery<T>(searchParams?: URLSearchParams): T | undefined {
    if (!searchParams) return
    const parsedQueries: T = {} as T
    for (const [key, value] of searchParams.entries()) {
      parsedQueries[key] = value
    }
    return parsedQueries
  }
}
```

I tried to use `parseQuery<T extends Record<string, any>>` but it doesn't work

Comment: Does [this appraoch](https://tsplay.dev/mbyo8N) work for you? It will also accept arrays. If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: It works but I got error at this row `parsedQueries[key] = value`

Comment: well, that's  outside of the question's context, but the easiest fix is `parsedQueries[key as keyof T] = value as T[keyof T]`